# Resizing images in java

Tags: java, image, swing, resize

So I've recently made this java code which displays images in java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Images extends JFrame {

    private ImageIcon image1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private ImageIcon image2;
    private JLabel label2;

    Images() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("IMG_20210928_221239.jpg"));

        label1 = new JLabel(image1);
        add(label1);

        image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("IMG_20210927_182247.jpg"));
        
        label2 = new JLabel(image2);
        add(label2);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Images gui = new Images();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setTitle("Image Program");
    }

}
```

And it works, but the only problem is that I have 2 images, but the 1st one is too large. I want to resize it, but I don't know how.

Comment: The [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) class has a getScaledInstance method.  Read the image files into Image instances, modify the Imager instances as you wish, and finally, convert the Image instances to ImageIcon instances for display.

Comment: While rescaling image sizes at run-time is possible, it makes more sense to rescale them before they are put in the project.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc, Andrew Thompson thanks. I will use this helpful advice.